# how to rewrite %20 in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to perform an equivalent rewrite to:

```
RewriteRule ^/this%20file.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

How do I handle the %20?

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^/this\%20file.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/this(\s|%20)file.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

but these have not worked.

The website is part of a Wordpress network, so it doesn't have it's own directory or subdomain where I can place a .htaccess file containing redirects; it's a virtual subdomain with domain mapping.  So, the Wordpress .htaccess rewriterule is preceeded by

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't need to use percent encoding/hexcode in mod_rewrite parameters since mod_rewrite will encode special characters (`?`, `#`, , `&`, etc.) by default. To write a space in the rewrite pattern, use `\s` or just escape the space with a backslash (`\`). Whether space gets encoded as `%20` or `+` depends on whether it's part of the query string or the URI.

So your rule should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/this\ file.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

Or:

```
RewriteRule ^/this\sfile.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

If you do want to manually specify the URI encoding, then you need to use the `NE` (`noescape`) flag to tell mod_rewrite not to escape special characters.

Otherwise, `/this%20file.pdf` gets treated as `/this%2520file.pdf`, as the `%` will be encoded as `%25`.

Comment: Thanks Lese.  How do you use the NE (noescape) flag?

Comment: If the solution is to use \s, why didn't (\s|%20) work?

Comment: @Steve: the `NE` flag is just placed in the square brackets at the end like with the `NC` and other flags. You separate them with commas if you want to use more than one flag. As for your second question, `(\s|%20)` should have worked. The parentheses and `%20` are unnecessary, but it doesn't get in the way either. I've tested it on my own server, and it does in fact work. Perhaps you've got something else interfering with the rewrite rule such as an incorrect `RewriteBase` directive or `example.com` needs to be `www.example.com`?

Comment: @Steve: Does the rewrite rule work if you try it without a space in the pattern URL? Is there a previous rule using the `C` (chain) flag? If there are rules after it, you may want to use the `L` flag to ensure no other rules get applied after it.

Comment: On Open Light Speed servers it may be necessary to put \ before file extension.
RewriteRule ^/this\ is\ the\ file\.pdf http://www.example.com/ [R=301, L]

Comment: @KH Strictly speaking, the literal dot should be backslash-escaped in the regex (on Apache or LiteSpeed) to prevent it matching _anything_ (its special meaning) - but it doesn't _need_ to be escaped for it to "work".

Comment: "You shouldn't need to use percent encoding in mod_rewrite parameters since mod_rewrite will encode special characters ... by default." - You don't need to use %-encoding in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, not because mod_rewrite encodes special characters, but because the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is already %-decoded. Likewise, the `NE` (`noescape`) flag is irrelevant here. The `NE` flag affects the _substitution_ string in the HTTP response, it makes no difference to the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` directive, as would seem to be implied here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/this%20file.pdf http://www.example.com/
> ```

The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (regex) is already %-decoded. So, to match an encoded *space* (ie. `%20`) in the request you match against a literal *space* in the regex.

(*Aside:* If you try to match a literal `%20` here then you are matching against a doubly-encoded *space*, ie. `%2520`, in the requested URL-path.)

As mentioned in @Lèsemajesté answer, you can do this in the regex itself by either backslash-escaping the *space* ie. `\` , or using the `\s` shorthand character class to match any whitespace character.

OR, you can simply surround the argument in double-quotes and use a literal un-escaped *space*. For example:

```
RewriteRule "^/?this file\.pdf" http://www.example.com/
```

The double-quotes are an Apache mechanism for when arguments contain *spaces*, since *spaces* are argument delimiters in Apache config files.

NB: Since we are dealing with `.htaccess` here you should also remove (or make optional - as I have done above) the slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In a *directory* context (ie. `.htaccess`) the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.